# Change a List item color if the selected one matches the solution

Tags: flutter

I store the alternatives as fields `option1`, `option2`, ... in the database.
The answer is stored as `solution`.

`var` to generate a list with the `numberOfOptions` stored:

```
 var alternatives = List<String>.generate(output['numberOfOptions'],(int index) => 'option${index + 1}');
```

`ListView.builder`:

```
                   ListView.builder(
                                physics:
                                    const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                itemCount: alternatives.length,
                                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                                  return GestureDetector(
                                      child: Text(
                                        output[alternatives[i]],
                                        style:  const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey),
                                      ),
                                      onTap: () {
                                       
                                        if (output['solution'] ==
                                            output[alternatives[i]]) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            isCorrect = true;
                                          });
                                        } else {
                                          setState(() {
                                            isCorrect = false;
                                          });
                                        }
                                       
                                      }
                                      
                                      );
                                })
```

I'm having difficulties trying to change the color of the alternative if the solution matches the selected alternative. How can I do it?

Comment: So, you want the Text color of the alternative to be different if `output['solution'] == output[alternatives[i]]`?

Comment: @StackUnderflow yes, it would be green. Otherwise, red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1º: I stored a new field in the database with the name of the field of the correct answer: `sol`

2º: created a int where the value stored will be the index of the correct option in the alternatives list:

```
int indexOfTheRightOption = alternatives.indexWhere((element) => element == output['sol']);
```

3º: _selectedIndex int and onSelected function:

```
  int? _selectedIndex;
_onSelected(int index) {
setState(() {
  _selectedIndex = index;
});
}
```

4º Color function:

```
 Color color(int? selectedIndex, int indexOfOPtion, int i) {
if (selectedIndex == null) {
  return Colors.grey;
}
if (selectedIndex == i && indexOfOPtion == selectedIndex) {
  return Colors.green;
}
if (selectedIndex == i && indexOfOPtion != selectedIndex) {
  return Colors.red;
}
return Colors.grey;
 }
```

5º add the function to color in TExtStyle:

```
  color: color(_selectedIndex, indexOfTheRightOption, i)
```

6º onTap function:

```
         onTap: () {
               _onSelected(i);
                            }
```

Extra: when navigating to next ou previous page, set the state of _selectedIndex to null:

```
 setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = null;
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a mechanism to keep track of the answers:

```
var answers = List<String>.generate(output['numberOfOptions'],(int index) => 'unanswered');
```

Base the color on the answer:

```
Text(
  output[alternatives[i]],
  style: TextStyle(
    color: answers[i] == 'unanswered'
      ? Colors.grey
      : answers[i] == 'correct'
        ? Colors.green
        : Colors.red,
  ),
)
```

Update answer in onTap:

```
onTap: () {
  if (output['solution'] == output[alternatives[i]]) {
    setState(() {
      answers[i] = 'correct';
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      answers[i] = 'incorrect';
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I may have not explained well. Bascially, its for a quiz app. After the user tap the alternative, if its right, turns green. Otherwise, red

Comment: So each alternative needs a property to track whether it is unanswered, answered correctly, or answered incorrectly.

Comment: Its a good start

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I managed do get the answer, will upload it soon